# Selective merge of state in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I've got the following to setup state in React:

```
  initPlatforms() {
    this.setState({rules: [
      {what: "platform", matches: "ios"},
      {what: "platform", matches: "android"},
      {what: "platform", matches: "windows"},
      {what: "platform", matches: "linux"},
      {what: "platform", matches: "mac"},
    ]})
  }
```

Thing is, I want to do a selective merge with the existing state. If something matches on the `what/matches` fields, just ignore it and add the remaining ones. An example of an existing state might be:

```
{"id":"cbd6defd-5f60-447f-8d31-f9ce75a7604a","matches":"android","url":"http://www.google.co.uk","what":"platform"}
```

How can I easily just add the missing states, without overwriting the original state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the news rules and check of they exist on the existing state.

```js
const existingState = {
  rules: [{
    "id": "cbd6defd-5f60-447f-8d31-f9ce75a7604a",
    "matches": "android",
    "url": "http://www.google.co.uk",
    "what": "platform"
  }]
}

const rules = [
      {what: "platform", matches: "ios"},
      {what: "platform", matches: "android"},
      {what: "platform", matches: "windows"},
      {what: "platform", matches: "linux"},
      {what: "platform", matches: "mac"}
    ]

const mergedState = rules.reduce((merged, rule) => {
  if (!merged.some(({what, matches}) => rule.what === what && rule.matches === matches)) 
    merged.push(rule)
  return merged
}, existingState.rules.slice())

console.log(mergedState);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get what you want to do. Just use the javascript spread method if you want to add elements to the state, like that:

```js
const addState = {
"id":"cbd6defd-5f60-447f-8d31-f9ce75a7604a",
"matches":"android",
"url":"http://www.google.co.uk",
"what":"platform"
}

this.setState({rules: [... this.state.rules, addState]})
```

with `...this.state.rules`, you are adding all the existing state, and adding this new thing to it.

Cheers!

Comment: I'm trying to match on `matches` and `what`; I don't want to overwrite or duplicate a state (trying your solution now)

Answer (score 0):

```
const rules = [
  {what: "platform", matches: "ios"},
  {what: "platform", matches: "android"},
  {what: "platform", matches: "windows"},
  {what: "platform", matches: "linux"},
  {what: "platform", matches: "mac"},
];

const { what, platform } = this.state;

this.setState({
  rules: rules.filter((rule) => rule.what !== what || rule.platform !== platform)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, that's very helpful. I have a question though; won't this only work when there is only one pre-existing rule?

Comment: If there's no pre-existing rule, I assume your component state would maybe look like this `{ id: "cbd6", matches: null, url: null, what: null }`. Then the expression `rules.filter((rule) => rule.what !== what || rule.platform !== platform)` will return your whole array of rules since the comparison `rule.what !== what || rule.platform !== platform` will always be evaluated as true. So I guess that works, it depends on what behavior you're trying to implement here.